# Can i use a postgres text_pattern_ops index with a variable string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm refining a Postgres text search query to ensure that all available indexes are used where possible. I have a text_pattern_obs btree index on a text column and the index has been shown to work using a simple query like:

```
set enable_seqscan = off; -- ensure that indexes are used even on small tables for this demo
```

```
select * from search_table where text_column like 'example'
```

^^ this gives me a super quick query using the proper index.

But when I want to substitute my 'example' text with a single string value that is a result of a previous function or select, it reverts to a full sequential table scan.

```
with user_input as (select 'example%' as query_string)
select * from search_table, user_input where text_column like query_string
```

^^ this is slow

I've tried type casting query_string::text etc but without any luck. And I can't just insert the string into the sql directly, because it's unknown until other queries execute.

I'm using postgres v11 so should have all the latest query plan cleverness available.

Comment: v12 is available, and has extra cleverness in this area.  But your example is not very realistic (why can you hard code the value into one part of the query, but not a different part?) so I don't know if that extra cleverness will help your real case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a prepared statement instead of a join:

With:

```
create table t(x int, y text);
create index fts on t(y text_pattern_ops);
insert into t values(1, 'example');
insert into t values(2, 'examples');
insert into t values(3, 'aaa');
insert into t values(4, 'zzz zzz');
analyze t;
set enable_seqscan = off;
```

I have:

```
 select * from t;
     x |    y     
    ---+----------
     1 | example
     2 | examples
     3 | aaa
     4 | zzz zzz
    (4 rows)

   explain analyze select * from t where y like 'example';
                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fts on t  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (y = 'example'::text)
   Filter: (y ~~ 'example'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.111 ms
 Execution Time: 0.030 ms
(5 rows)

explain analyze select * from t where y like 'example%';
                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fts on t  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=2 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((y ~>=~ 'example'::text) AND (y ~<~ 'examplf'::text))
   Filter: (y ~~ 'example%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.140 ms
 Execution Time: 0.014 ms
(5 rows)

explain analyze with user_input as (select 'example%' as query_string)
select * from t, user_input where y like query_string;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                  

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----
 Nested Loop  (cost=10000000000.01..10000000001.15 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.008..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (t.y ~~ user_input.query_string)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2
   CTE user_input
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000001.04 rows=4 width=11) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=4 loops
=1)
   ->  CTE Scan on user_input  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=4)
 Planning Time: 0.049 ms
 Execution Time: 0.031 ms
(9 rows)

prepare s1(text) as select * from t where y like $1;
PREPARE
explain analyze execute s1('example%');
                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fts on t  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=2 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((y ~>=~ 'example'::text) AND (y ~<~ 'examplf'::text))
   Filter: (y ~~ 'example%'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.089 ms
 Execution Time: 0.023 ms
(5 rows)
```